# get Warning: got packets out of order. Expected 2 but received 0

Tags: packet, mysql2

I'm using node mysql2 driver to connect to mysql 8 on linux, the front end runs into stuck many times and i guess it would be related to the message "Warning: got packets out of order. Expected 2 but received 0", i searched web and somebody says increasing max_allowed_packet could help. but seems it's already 1GB?
show variables like '%max%all%';
+---------------------------+------------+
| Variable_name             | Value      |
+---------------------------+------------+
| max_allowed_packet        | 1073741824 |
| mysqlx_max_allowed_packet | 67108864   |
| slave_max_allowed_packet  | 1073741824 |
+---------------------------+------------+
i guess need put some mysql2 driver option but don't know what's that option,
anybody can help? thanks.

Thanks & Regards,
Martin.